# Use of 「として」in this sentence

Tags: grammar, translation

今後もお客様との対話の窓口として、より充実していくべく努力してまいります

Given translation: We are working from here in an effort to provide a more fulfilling window for customer interaction.

Does 窓口として mean that someone is working from the 窓口?

Answer (score 3):

「として」is a set phrase meaning "as, in the role of", derived from the continuative form of 「とする」+ conjunctive particle 「て」.

「窓口として」means "as a window". This sounds a bit weird, doesn't it? Let's put it back into the context. The noun phrase modified by 「として」is actually 「お客様との対話の窓口」, not just 「窓口」. 「窓口」is used figuratively here.

お客様との対話の窓口として: as a channel of communication with the customers

> 今後もお客様との対話の窓口として、より充実していくべく努力してまいります

A rough rendition of this in English goes something like this:

> [We] will continue to work hard as a channel of communication with our customers, making it even better than before.